# np.tensordot function, how to multiply a tensor by successive slices of another?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, tensor, tensordot

I want to multiply two 3D tensors in a specific way.
The two tensors have shapes `T1 = (a,b,c)` and `T2 = (d,b,c)`.

What I want is to multiply `a` times `T2` by the successive 'slices' `(b,c)` of `a`.
In other words, I want to have the same as this code :

```py
import numpy as np

a=2
b=3
c=4
d=5

T1 = np.random.rand(a,b,c)
T2 = np.random.rand(d,b,c)


L= []
for j in range(a) :
    L+=[T1[j,:,:]*T2]
L = np.array(L)
L.shape
```

I have the iterative solution and I try with axes arguments but I didn't succeed in the second way.

Comment: I don't get what is the result you need. You want to multiply every (b,c) slice of T1 with T2 that has shape (d,b,c), do you want to perform a cross product? or the dot product?

Comment: Hi imburningbabe, I need every slice (b,c) to be multiply by T2, it's equivalent to repeat 'd' times each slice (b,c) to have a (d,b,c) tensor, and then multiply it element by element with T2. And this for each (b,c) slice of T1. Thank you !

Comment: So the final dimension of you tensor should be T3 = (a x d, b, c) ?

Comment: No i want another dimension so that the final result is (a,d,b,c).

Comment: I have updated the post so that you can run the code, I hope it'll be more clear :)

Comment: `np.einsum('abc, dbc -> adbc', T1, T2)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I think I got the solution:

```
a=2
b=3
c=4
d=5

T1 = np.random.rand(a,b,c)
T2 = np.random.rand(d,b,c)

L = np.zeros(shape=(a,d,b,c))
for i1 in range(len(T1)):
    for i2 in range(len(T2)):
        L[i1,i2] = np.multiply(np.array(T1[i1]),np.array(T2[i2]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! But what I want is to avoid loops and compute this result using one vectorized function. I think it should be possible with np.tensordot  (or another) and some good axis parameters.

Comment: Yeah, maybe you are right. But tensor products don't work that way, in your case what you can multiply are tensors of the shape (b,c,a) and (c,b,d), with that sequence of dimension. Moreover, in a tensordot product what you get is the dot product between matrices, that is completely different from an elementwise multiplication

Answer (score 0):

Since the shapes:

```
In [26]: T1.shape, T2.shape
Out[26]: ((2, 3, 4), (5, 3, 4))
```

produce a:

```
In [27]: L.shape
Out[27]: (2, 5, 3, 4)
```

Let's try a `broadcasted` pair of arrays:

```
In [28]: res = T1[:,None]*T2[None,:]
```

Shape and values match:

```
In [29]: res.shape
Out[29]: (2, 5, 3, 4)    
In [30]: np.allclose(L,res)
Out[30]: True
```

`tensordot`, `dot`, or `matmul` don't apply; just plain elementwise multiplication, with `broadcasting`.